# Keep Getting Cannot Find symbol Error - Java

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, javafx-8, alert

i don't understand why i keep getting these errors in several locations, when i try to run the program:
"error: cannot find symbol"

"package javafx.scene.control.Alert does not exist
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;"

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
public class MainView implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TextField hoursField;

@FXML
private TextField minutesField;

@FXML
private TextField secondsField;

private final AlarmController alarmController;

@FXML
private void startAlarm(ActionEvent event) {
    int response = this.alarmController.startAlarm(
        this.hoursField.getText(), 
        this.minutesField.getText(),
        this.secondsField.getText()
    );

    if (response == Alarm.ERROR_INVALID_INPUT) {
        this.showWarning("Please enter a number only for the times!", "Invalid input received");
    } else if (response == Alarm.ERROR_ALARM_ALREADY_ON) {
        this.showWarning("An alarm is already running at the moment! If you wish to override the current alarm, please stop it first!", "Cannot override current alarm.");
    } else if (response == Alarm.ERROR_NO_TIME_SET) {
        this.showWarning("You cannot set an alarm for 0 seconds! Please set a realistic time.", "No time set");
    } else {
        this.showSuccessfulMessage("Successfully scheduled alarm!", "Success");
    }
}

public void showWarning(String message, String title) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText(message);
    alert.showAndWait();
}

public void showSuccessfulMessage(String message, String title) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText(message);
    alert.showAndWait();
}

@FXML
private void stopAlarm(ActionEvent event) {
    this.alarmController.stopAlarm();

    this.showSuccessfulMessage("Successfully stopped the alarm!", "Success");
}


public MainView() {
    this.alarmController = new AlarmController();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}
```

}

Comment: what is `Alarm` ?

Comment: check your netbeans java build path options

Comment: @Shashwat it's a class in the project

Comment: @BillF How do i do that, please?

Comment: [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/project-setup.html#projects-classpath) and see if your build path is on Java 1.8

Comment: @BillF it's on Java 1.8

Comment: @DavidNode then it should be fine. I unfortunately haven't used netbeans a lot. You might want to search for common bugs on netbeans. I **feel** like it an issue with netbeans not importing the proper jars

Comment: You opened [the same question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982820/java-fxml-app-not-working-cannot-find-symbol-error), where I posted an answer on your problem.