# Java fxml app not working - Cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, javafx-8, alert

i downloaded a java fxml app from https://github.com/HassanAlthaf/AlarmApplication
and when i try to run it a get a "cannot find symbol" error from the MainView.java class. Here is the code from the Mainview.java file

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
public class MainView implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TextField hoursField;

@FXML
private TextField minutesField;

@FXML
private TextField secondsField;

private final AlarmController alarmController;

@FXML
private void startAlarm(ActionEvent event) {
    int response = this.alarmController.startAlarm(
        this.hoursField.getText(), 
        this.minutesField.getText(),
        this.secondsField.getText()
    );

    if (response == Alarm.ERROR_INVALID_INPUT) {
        this.showWarning("Please enter a number only for the times!", "Invalid input received");
    } else if (response == Alarm.ERROR_ALARM_ALREADY_ON) {
        this.showWarning("An alarm is already running at the moment! If you wish to override the current alarm, please stop it first!", "Cannot override current alarm.");
    } else if (response == Alarm.ERROR_NO_TIME_SET) {
        this.showWarning("You cannot set an alarm for 0 seconds! Please set a realistic time.", "No time set");
    } else {
        this.showSuccessfulMessage("Successfully scheduled alarm!", "Success");
    }
}

public void showWarning(String message, String title) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText(message);
    alert.showAndWait();
}

public void showSuccessfulMessage(String message, String title) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText(message);
    alert.showAndWait();
}

@FXML
private void stopAlarm(ActionEvent event) {
    this.alarmController.stopAlarm();

    this.showSuccessfulMessage("Successfully stopped the alarm!", "Success");
}


public MainView() {
    this.alarmController = new AlarmController();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}
```

}

Comment: which is the symbol, it can't find ?

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: @Michael how do i do that please?

Comment: @DavidNode on which line does it give the error ?

Comment: @Shashwat line 54 and line 62

Comment: This is a compile error. It should explicitly tell you which "symbol" it cannot find. (Also, you are the only one who can see line numbers here...)

Comment: are you using java version >= 8u40? At least on guthub the lines are the ones where the `Alert`s are created...

Comment: am using java 8u25 @fabian

Comment: am getting the error in the " Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);"  and "Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);" part of the code.

Comment: @DavidNode please update to a newer version of the JDK, these Alert-Classes are not present in you version of the JDK, they where introduces java 8u40 or above

Answer (score 0):

Your error message should be similar to the following:

> [javac] cannot find symbol
>
> [javac] import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
>
> [javac] ..........................................^
>
> [javac]   symbol:   class Alert

As it has been said in the comments: The [Alert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) class has been introduced in Java 8u40.
For further changes that have been introduced on the 8u40 release [see this Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/jdk-8u40-released).

So: Update your Java distribution, either [by downloading it on the Oracle page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html), or by updating it via `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk openjfx -y`